# How to apply where condition on collection result in Laravel?

Tags: php, laravel

I want to get all notifications and then in specific case apply `where` condition on that result.

```
$allNotifications = $user->notifications()->unread()->orderBy('created_at', 'desc')->get();
```

then i will check if some condition is occurred so apply another `where` condition on above collection.

```
$notifications = $allNotifications->where('created_at', '>', $timestamps);
```

It means get those notifications from `$allNotifications` that matched with defined condition.

Comment: Try something like $allNotifications = $user->notifications(function($query) use ($timestamps) {return $query->where('created_at', '>', $timestamps); })->unread()->orderBy('created_at', 'desc')->get();

Answer (score 1):

Use `filter()` method:

```
$notifications = $allNotifications->filter(function ($item) use ($timestamp) {
    return $item->created_at > $timestamp;
});

$notifications->all();
```